# Saving EditText in bundle and restoring it on layout change

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, bundle

I have created 2 different layouts for the same Fragment. One is for `Portrait` and second for `Landscape`. I have an `EditText` field which content I want to pass over if I change the orientation, so the layout switches. The value is saved and it is printed out in Log.d when the `onViewCreated` is called, but it is not set in the `EditText` field.
I also noticed, it is only saved at first time, and on every change the bundle is multiplied. Any other input in run time is ignored.

Following out:

```
02-07 10:26:15.100 9968-9968/parohyApps.antdiary D/NewData: Bundle string > hi
02-07 10:26:18.780 9968-9968/parohyApps.antdiary I/System.out: 2131492950
02-07 10:26:23.300 9968-9968/parohyApps.antdiary D/NewData: Bundle string > hi
02-07 10:26:23.340 9968-9968/parohyApps.antdiary D/NewData: Bundle string > hi
02-07 10:26:24.430 9968-9968/parohyApps.antdiary W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
02-07 10:26:25.570 9968-9968/parohyApps.antdiary W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
02-07 10:26:32.380 9968-9968/parohyApps.antdiary D/NewData: Bundle string > hi
02-07 10:26:32.400 9968-9968/parohyApps.antdiary D/NewData: Bundle string > hi
02-07 10:26:32.430 9968-9968/parohyApps.antdiary D/NewData: Bundle string > hi
02-07 10:26:32.550 9968-9968/parohyApps.antdiary I/Choreographer: Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Code:

```
public class NewData extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_data_layout, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        Log.d("NewData", "Bundle string > " + savedInstanceState.getString("outString", "NO STRING"));
        EditText name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        name.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("outString", 
                                                   "NO STRING"));
    }

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    EditText name = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.et_name);
    outState.putString("outString",name.getText().toString());
   }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `onRestoreInstanceState()`

Comment: According to documentation, it is called when the Activity or Fragment was closed/killed by the OS/user and than reopened. Now you suggested, I tried, but it is not called when I change from portrait>landscape.

Comment: I think you have to save your fragment in activity's onSavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

Comment: OK bro I will add it as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to save your fragment in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` of your **Activity**, like:

**Save Fragment**

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
   getFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"yourFragment",yourFragment);
}
```

**Restore Fragment**

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState){
    yourFragment = getFragmentManager().getFragment(inState,"yourFragment");
}
```

Comment: It wont accept the fragment. I have `android.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` is required in `puFragment()`. Tried to import `android.support.v4.app.Fragmen` in NewData fragment but than the `FragmentTransaction` complains about the type.

Comment: have you tried getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment. And are you sure and your Activity extends ActionBarActivity ?

Comment: no. My activity extends `AppCompatActivity` which contains Fragments

Comment: It's OK that was deprecated. I think you are combining support package with non support package which result to incompatible error. Please recheck your fragments and activities. Use the same everywhere. Either use support fragment or only fragment everywhere. I am about to leave now. Leave comment if you again have got same issue. I will catch up later.

Comment: I managed to use the v4 fragment. It is working. Thank you for your help!